Qt Widgets | Strange QMdiArea's subwindow behaviour
here is the problem:
I have a menubar in my MainWindow. When adding a subwindow to QMdiArea and trying to maximize it, it's header, for some reason, idk why, sets on menubar. It looks like this:
Click
Its too horrible, especially when u have, for example, a menu bar with a lot of sub menus.
As a result, im trying to find solution to maximize window in boundaries of qmdiarea
I would be very grateful if u provide me some solutions.
UPD: Also, is there any way to disable Qt icon, but not via setting a pixel (1,1) in it
I only found old topics where people said that this behavior is normal.. o_o

Thats how MDI areas have always worked, Qt is just following the convention. If you don't want that, you have to prevent maximization of the window, or eventually detect maximize requests and then act accordingly, but this also means that you need to manage the subwindow geometries whenever the top level window is resized.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
